# Infinite loop due to twilio studio

Tags: twilio

I was experimenting with Twilio Studio, and well I accidentally infinite looped (only to my main number).

My account doesn't have that many credits left. Do you guys stop sending messages after the credit expires ? Or just auto-charge my CC after. Do failed message count towards this charge ?

What I tried to stop the loop:

- Pressed STOP (didn't do much becausec too many messages we're being queued)
- blocked the number (that worked)
- Then I Deleted my studio flow, released my number, deleted all my services. To attempt to mitigate the potential message "Failed" cost (again, not sure if that charges or not)

It's been about an hour so it says I got charged 40 cents. I don't know if this accurate. But what is the correct way to stop an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many questions in this post, so please forgive me if I miss one:

**Q:** Does Twilio auto recharge your CC?

**A:** It depends on whether you enabled this [option in the billing settings](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135607-How-do-I-set-a-recharge-or-notification-trigger-) [image: auto recharge option]

**Q:** What happens if your account balance hits zero?

**A:** If you don't refill your balance, all consecutive messages will fail. From the [help page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183248-What-happens-if-my-Twilio-balance-reaches-zero-):

> While suspended, you will be blocked from all Twilio usage, including phone calls, video, messages and more.

**Q:** Do failed message count towards this charge?

**A:** What do you mean with failed? I assume you mean the message delivery failed because the balance was zero. Then, there's no cost.

**Q:** But what is the correct way to stop an infinite loop?

**A:** You can terminate Studio flow executions in the log (*Stop Execution*). I think that would be the best option:
[image: cancel execution]